# Output to .txt not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am attempting to output the following commands result/output to a .txt file in the same location the .cmd script is located.

```
@ECHO OFF
@rem ----[ This code block detects if the script is being running with admin PRIVILEGES If it isn't it pauses and then quits]-------
echo OFF
NET SESSION >nul 2>&1
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    ECHO Administrator PRIVILEGES Detected! 
) ELSE (
   echo ######## ########  ########   #######  ########  
   echo ##       ##     ## ##     ## ##     ## ##     ## 
   echo ##       ##     ## ##     ## ##     ## ##     ## 
   echo ######   ########  ########  ##     ## ########  
   echo ##       ##   ##   ##   ##   ##     ## ##   ##   
   echo ##       ##    ##  ##    ##  ##     ## ##    ##  
   echo ######## ##     ## ##     ##  #######  ##     ## 
   echo.
   echo.
   echo ####### ERROR: ADMINISTRATOR PRIVILEGES REQUIRED #########
   echo This script must be run as administrator to work properly!  
   echo If you're seeing this after clicking on the icon, then right click on the script and select "Run As Administrator".
   echo ##########################################################
   echo.
   PAUSE
   EXIT /B 1
)
@echo ON
@echo OFF
call :out >output.txt
exit /b

:out
rem -- This ends tasktree on LEAP Desktop.exe --
Taskkill /IM "LEAPWDSService.exe" /F
Taskkill /IM "LEAP Office Documents.exe" /F
Taskkill /IM "LEAP Office Documents client.exe" /F
Taskkill /IM "LEAP Office Accounting.exe" /F
Taskkill /IM "LEAP Office Accounting client.exe" /F

rem -- This uninstalls LEAP V10 32-Bit from the PC --
@Echo Uninstalling LEAP Office Documents Client for 32-Bit Operating Systems, This may take a few minutes...
@Echo Off
Title LEAP Office Documents Client for 32-Bit Operating Systems
Echo LEAP Office Documents Client for 32-Bit Operating Systems
WMIC Product Where "Name='LEAP Office Documents Client for 32-Bit Operating Systems'" Call Uninstall /NoInteractive

@Echo Uninstalling LEAP Office Accounting Client for 32-Bit Operating Systems, This may take a few minutes...
@Echo Off
Title LEAP Office Accounting Client for 32-Bit Operating Systems
Echo LEAP Office Accounting Client for 32-Bit Operating Systems
WMIC Product Where "Name='LEAP Office Accounting Client for 32-Bit Operating Systems'" Call Uninstall /NoInteractive

@Echo Uninstalling LEAP Office Accounting Single User for 32-Bit Operating Systems, This may take a few minutes...
@Echo Off
Title LEAP Office Accounting Single User for 32-Bit Operating Systems
Echo LEAP Office Accounting Single User for 32-Bit Operating Systems
WMIC Product Where "Name='LEAP Office Accounting Single User for 32-Bit Operating Systems'" Call Uninstall /NoInteractive

@Echo Uninstalling LEAP Office Documents Single User for 32-Bit OS, This may take a few minutes...
@Echo Off
Title LEAP Office Documents Single User for 32-Bit OS
Echo LEAP Office Documents Single User for 32-Bit OS
WMIC Product Where "Name='LEAP Office Documents Single User for 32-Bit OS'" Call Uninstall /NoInteractive

rem -- This uninstalls LEAP V10 64-Bit from the PC --
@Echo Uninstalling LEAP Office Documents Client for 64-Bit Operating Systems, This may take a few minutes...
@Echo Off
Title LEAP Office Documents Client for 64-Bit Operating Systems
Echo LEAP Office Documents Client for 64-Bit Operating Systems
WMIC Product Where "Name='LEAP Office Documents Client for 64-Bit Operating Systems'" Call Uninstall /NoInteractive

@Echo Uninstalling LEAP Office Accounting Client for 64-Bit Operating Systems, Please follow the prompts...
@Echo Off
Set "GUID="

For /F "Tokens=2Delims==}" %%A In ('WMIC Product Where "Name='LEAP Office Accounting Client for 64-Bit Operating Systems'" Get IdentifyingNumber /Value 2^>Nul') Do Set "GUID=%%A}"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\%GUID%\setup.exe" /m:uninstall

@Echo Uninstalling LEAP Office Accounting Single User for 64-Bit Operating Systems, Please follow the prompts...
@Echo Off
Set "GUID="

For /F "Tokens=2Delims==}" %%A In ('WMIC Product Where "Name='LEAP Office Accounting Single User for 64-Bit Operating Systems'" Get IdentifyingNumber /Value 2^>Nul') Do Set "GUID=%%A}"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\%GUID%\setup.exe" /m:uninstall

@Echo Uninstalling LEAP Office Documents Single User for 64-Bit OS, This may take a few minutes...
@Echo Off
Title LEAP Office Documents Single User for 64-Bit OS
Echo LEAP Office Documents Single User for 64-Bit OS
WMIC Product Where "Name='LEAP Office Documents Single User for 64-Bit OS'" Call Uninstall /NoInteractive

@Echo Removing LEAP PDF Registry Keys...
reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\LEAPAccountingPDFPrinter /f

@Echo Leap Uninstaller complete, Removing and Renaming Leap Files...
@Echo Off
@Echo ############## AppData Folder Local ############## 

@Echo Delete: AppData/Local/LEAP
@Echo Off
RD /S /Q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\LEAP"
@Echo ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

@Echo Delete: AppData/Local/LEAP Office Installations 
@Echo Off
RD /S /Q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\LEAP Office Installations"
@Echo ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

@Echo Delete: AppData/Local/LEAP_Legal
@Echo Off
RD /S /Q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\LEAP_Legal"
@Echo ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

@Echo Delete: AppData/Local/LEAP Desktop 
@Echo Off
RD /S /Q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\LEAP Desktop"
@Echo ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

@Echo Delete: AppData/Local/LEAP_Legal_Software 
@Echo Off
RD /S /Q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\LEAP_Legal_Software"
@Echo ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

@Echo Delete: AppData/Roaming/4D
@Echo Off
RD /S /Q "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\4D"
@Echo ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

@Echo Delete: AppData/Roaming/LEAP Legal Software
@Echo Off
RD /S /Q "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\LEAP Legal Software"
@Echo ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

@Echo Delete: AppData/Roaming/LEAP_Timesheet
@Echo Off
RD /S /Q "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\LEAP_Timesheet"
@Echo ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

@Echo Delete: AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Word/startup/LEAP03automation.dtom
@Echo Off
RD /S /Q "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\word\startup\LEAP03automation.dotm"
@Echo ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

@Echo ################# Program Files #################
@Echo Off

@Echo Delete: Program Files/LEAP Office 
@Echo Off
RD /S /Q "C:\Program Files\LEAP Office"
@Echo ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

@Echo Delete: Program Files/LEAP Legal Software 
@Echo Off
RD /S /Q "C:\Program Files\LEAP Legal Software"
@Echo ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

@Echo ############## Program Files (x86) ##############
@Echo Off

@Echo Delete: Program Files (x86)/LEAP Office 
@Echo Off
RD /S /Q "C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAP Office"
@Echo ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

@Echo Delete: Program Files (x86)/LEAP Legal Software 
@Echo Off
RD /S /Q "C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAP Legal Software"
@Echo ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

@Echo  ################# Temp #################
@Echo Off

@Echo Delete: Temp/4D
@Echo Off
RD /S /Q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\4D"
@Echo ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

@Echo Delete: Temp/LEAP
@Echo Off
RD /S /Q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\LEAP"
@Echo ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

@Echo Delete: Temp/LEAP_Legal
@Echo Off
RD /S /Q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\LEAP_Legal"
@Echo ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

@Echo Delete: Temp/LEAP_Cloud
@Echo Off
RD /S /Q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\LEAP_Cloud"
@Echo ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

@Echo Delete: Temp/LEAP_Desktop
@Echo Off
RD /S /Q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\LEAP_Desktop"
@Echo ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

@Echo Delete: Temp/accdoc folder
@Echo Off
RD /S /Q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\accdoc"
@Echo ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

@Echo Full Uninstall complete.
@Echo Off

pause

exit
```

Although when running the script no output.txt is created, What am I missing here?
I did try to add the script as well in the case there's and issue I am missing in the rest of the script but It wouldn't allow me to post it.

Comment: Edit your question and post the 30+ commands with your code !

Comment: I didn't realise I could edit it and post the remaining, thank you.

Comment: Irrespective of your specific issue, would in not make more sense to just run one uninstall command, i.e `WMIC Product Where "Name Like 'LEAP Office%%'" Call Uninstall`? Noting that you'd still need to get the GUID's first, _(this can probably be done from a single `For /F` loop first)_.

Comment: Instead of all of those `TaskKill` commands, you could probably terminate the executables similarly, `WMIC Process Where "Name Like 'LEAP%%'" Call Terminate` too! And the majority of your `RD` commands could also be made more simple by using `For` loops with the matching locations with `LEAP*` as well.

Comment: Additionally, `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp`=`%TEMP%`, `C:\Program Files (x86)`=`%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%`, `C:\Program Files`=`%PROGRAMFILES%`, `"%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming`=`%APPDATA%` and `%userprofile%\AppData\Local`=`%LOCALAPPDATA%`.

Comment: @compo Thank you for all the suggestions, any ideas on how to output the command output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`call :out > "%~dp0output.txt"` is output to same location as the script. `call /?` shows you modifiers for use.

Running as administrator, the previous `output.txt` is possibly in the `system32` folder.

If you want to output stderr as well, use:

```
call :out > "%~dp0output.txt" 2>&1
```

`2>&1` will redirect *stderr (2)* to the handle of *stdout (1)*.

Comment: I feel so stupid! I completely forgot the output location would be different if run as Admin!
Also is there a way for the output to display exactly as shown in CMD, E.g if command `RD /S /Q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\LEAP"` doesn't find a file then its not outputting that into the output.txt file
Also Thank you

Comment: Errors go to stderr. You are only redirecting stdout. Updated answer about redirecting stderr to handle of stdout which will output both streams.